# Mex fails to link correctly, resulting in "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mxGetNumberOfDimensions_700"

Tags: c, macos, linker, mex, matlab-compiler

I've been trying to recompile some old code I had on my new machine, but it fails consistently. I have reduced the problem down to a more or less minimal example.

The code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <mat.h>
#include <matrix.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *name;    
  int ndim;
  MATFile *pmat;
  mxArray *pa;
  pmat = matOpen("../orders/order_fractal_C1.mat", "r");
  pa = matGetNextVariable(pmat, &name);
  ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(pa);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the command

```
$MATLABROOT/bin/mex -v -f ~/matopts.sh CFLAGS="" -output test test.c
```

The matopts.sh file points mex to using gcc-5 (installed via homebrew).

The code compiles without errors or warnings, but on executing ./test I get

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: >_mxGetNumberOfDimensions_700
>    Referenced from: /Users/keith/Dropbox/Code/sphere/newparallel/C/./test
>    Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _mxGetNumberOfDimensions_700
>    Referenced from: /Users/keith/Dropbox/Code/sphere/newparallel/C/./test
>    Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

If I don't include the last line of code, all is well. What is going wrong? Why does it "expect" the symbol to be in libSystem.B.dylib, and not in matrix.h?

EDIT:
The whole matopts.sh file is rather large, all I did was change

```
CC='gcc'
```

to

```
CC='gcc-5'
```

in two instances, so it would not use clang.

EDIT 2:
I decided to go back to using clang, figuring that it is probably best to just accept the way Matlab wants to do things.

Now I can get it to work, but only when executing the command from within Matlab, either by compiling it as a `mexFunction` and calling the function in Matlab, or by compiling it with `-client engine`  and then running with `!./test`.

If I try to run it from outside Matlab, however, I get the same error as before.

Comment: It seems I messed up the opening bit of the code, and I can't edit it either, but it should read 
`#include <math.h>
#include <mat.h>
#include <matrix.h>`

Comment: Just click `edit` under your post.

Comment: matrix.h could give you the prototype of function, but the function must be somewhere... in a static lib, in a shared lib, or in our source code. You must put `libSystem.B.dylib` in a reachable dir, because your program wants it in a dynamic lib.

Comment: Of course, I should have known that matrix.h would not contain the function. But should I expect libSystem.B.dylib to actually contain mex-functions?

Comment: You just need to add `-largeArrayDims` (note case) to your `mex` command.

Comment: @chappjc Yes, that is true, that removes a warning from `mex`. But doesn't solve my problem. It does change to not finding `_mxGetNumberOfDimensions_730`, instead of `...700`.

Comment: Darn.  I think the `CFLAGS=""` is a problem.  Can you post your matopts.sh you used to get GCC 5 working.

Comment: You might be onto something, removing the CFLAGS="" results in `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:23:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yikes!  can't find stdlib.h... I don't think gcc-5 is configured/installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-largeArrayDims` (note the case) to your `mex` command.

If you are still having trouble, be sure you are not defining `MX_COMPAT_32` anywhere.